# How can I get the previous and next link hrefs from a list of hrefs?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that checks for click events on links inside of the 
element with id = menu:

```
$("#menu")
   .on('click', 'a[href^="/City"]', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#editLink').attr("data-href", link);
   });
```

The HTML that this code works on looks like this:

```
<ul class="controls-buttons question-grid" id="menu">
   <li class="question-grid"><a href="/City/0101004H">1</a></li>
   <li class="question-grid"><a href="/City/0101004I">2</a></li>
   <li class="question-grid"><a href="/City/0101004J">3</a></li>
   <li class="question-grid"><a href="/City/0101004K">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have two links on another part of my screen as below:

```
<a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a>
<a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
```

How can I make it so that if a user clicks on the "2" link then these links are changed to:

```
<a id="prev"  href="/City/0101004H" title="City 1">Prev</a>
<a id="next"  href="/City/0101004J" title="City 3">Next</a>
```

If a user clicks on the "1" that the links are changed to:

```
<a id="prev"  href="#"></a>
<a id="next"  href="/City/0101004J" title="City 2">Next</a>
```

If a user clicks on the last element in the list then the links are changed to:

```
<a id="prev"  href="/City/0101004H" title="City 3">Prev</a>
<a id="next"  href="#"></a>
```

For me the biggest problems is how to check if there are links before or after the current link. I know basic jQuery but I hope someone can help me with some suggestions.

Comment: What is the identifier you use for the CURRENT PAGE?
i.e. when you're on `/City/0101004H` how does your page look, does it make it bold or what?  This is something usually done server side or hard coded. Jquery should only be used when doing it with ajax or when you don't have content to paginate through instead of multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something like this :

```
$("#menu").on('click', 'a[href^="/City"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#editLink').attr("data-href", $(this).attr('href'));
});

$('#prev, #next').on('click', function() {
    var isNext = this.id==='next',
        liNow = $('#editLink').attr("data-href") || $('#menu li:first a').attr('href'),
        nextA = $('a[href="'+liNow+'"]', '#menu').parent('li')[isNext?'next':'prev']('li').find('a');
    if (!nextA.length) nextA = isNext ? $('#menu li:last a') : $('#menu li:first a');
    nextA.trigger('click');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/FMgXQ/)

Answer (score 0):

i don't test this but hope that useful :

```
$('.question-grid a').click(function(){

   var number=parseInt($(this).html());

   if(number<2)
   {
      $('#prev').attr('href','#');
      $('#next').attr('href',$(this).next('a').attr('href');
   }else if(number>1 && number<4){
      $('#prev').attr('href',$(this).prev('a').attr('href'));
      $('#next').attr('href',$(this).next('a').attr('href'));  
   }else{
      $('#prev').attr('href',$(this).prev('a').attr('href'));
      $('#next').attr('href','#'); 
   }
});
```